# Java-Can't override the method even though reference object is pointing to the subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have another sample program where it does override but all methods have same number of parameters.

```
class A {
    int a;
    // function with dummy parameters
    void printArray(int i) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //function with dummy parameters
    void printArray(int i, int s) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class JavaApplication5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ob = new A();
        B o2 = new B();
        A o3;
        o3 = o2;
        o3.printArray(3, 2); // It says that it can not be applied to given type :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't expect answers if you don't event care about the formatting of your question

Comment: Java typing system is static.  `o3` is of type `A`, so it doesn't have access to the two argument method.

Comment: There is no overriding happening in your code at all. You are just trying to call a method only defined in class B on a variable of type A.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want any errors, you need to tell the Java interpreter than o3 is able to call printArray(3,2) by casting. Mainly by doing

`((B)o3).printArray(3,2);`

Moreover, what you are doing is not overriding anything. (Notice your method paramter in class A and class B is different) Overriding would be something like this:

```
class A {
    int a;
    // function with dummy parameters
    void printArray(int i){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //function with dummy parameters
    @Override
    void printArray(int i) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ob = new A();
        B o2 = new B();
        A o3;
        o3 = o2;
        o3.printArray(3);
    }
}
```

Here you do not need to cast anything since class B overrides the method in class A. As far as the Java interpreter is concerned, any instance of class A AND class B can call printArray, so it doesn't matter if the object o3 is an instance of class A or class B.